# Could not chdir to home directory /opt/scm: Permission denied

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions

I'm trying to set up a simple repository host on my linux server under "/opt/scm", but I'm getting this error when attempting to SSH in as my scm user.

`Could not chdir to home directory /opt/scm: Permission denied`

I thought that I understood directory permissions, but clearly I'm doing something wrong...

This is what I've done.

```
cd /opt
$ sudo mkdir scm
$ sudo chown scm:scm scm/
$ sudo su scm
$ chmod 660 scm/
$ ls -l 
    drw-rw---- 2 scm   scm   4096 Aug 28 10:03 scm
```

Then ssh in `ssh scm@192.168.1.123`
and I get `Could not chdir to home directory /opt/scm: Permission denied`.

Shouldn't my scm user have access to the directory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are missing the executable bit, which allows you to enter the directory in the first place:

```
sudo chmod ug+x scm
```

Comment: Is that just what "executable" means on a directory then?

Comment: @ChrisCovert yes, the x bit gives permission to "be in" the directory.  Without it, you can't `cd` into the directory (or through it to a subdirectory, even if the subdirectory has x).